# Dual external monitors on Dell E-Port II docking station are mirroring with each other

Tags: linux, laptop, multi-monitor, dock-station

I have a Dell Latitude E7450 running Linux Mint running Mate and I'm using a Dell E-Port II (Model PRO3X) docking station.  I'm connecting two external monitors, one via DVI and the other using Display Port, for a total of three displays.  I can't get the external monitors to be independent and they are mirroring each other.  I have no issues with the laptop's display itself.

I've tried the proprietary driver and that didn't seem to help. In Windows 7 there is no problem.

This is the output of `xrandr`, which shows the dvi and displayport as "DP1", regardless if one or both are plugged in.  I can't get all three to show up when using the docking station.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1600x900+0+180 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1600x900       60.0*+   40.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 connected 1920x1080+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the `xrandr`  output, it seems two monitors have been recognized, `eDP1` and `DP1`. So perhaps try telling xrandr their orientation so xrandr will stop the default mirroring behavior, by one of these commands:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1600x900 --right-of DP1
```

or if more appropriate to have DP1 to right of eDP1 instead:

```
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP1
```

If doing this fixes your mirroring problem but causes your other monitor to suddenly take on the same resolution, you can fix by running  `xrandr --output <monitorname> --mode <desired resolution>` to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've updated my question to hopefully be less confusing.  I have a total of three displays, two external displays and the laptop.  Both external displays show up as DP1 regardless if one or both are plugged in.

Comment: I have the issue did you fix the problem